# highest and smallest number in javascript using only switch statement

Tags: javascript

i am wondering how to use switch statement to tell which is the highest and lowest number in javascript, without using math.max in my script, any help?

Comment: Homework, perhaps? Then tag it as such.

Comment: Please read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ - `possible-homework` is a meta-tag and adds nothing to the question. In addition, it would be polite to ask the OP first and give them a chance to retag as `homework`. There is ample precedent for questions here that look like homework but aren't.

Comment: Homework or not, I would like to see what OP has tried before going out and writing code for him/her. So OP, what have you tried thus far?  Do you have any thoughts on how you should proceed?

Comment: this is not a homework.well i have been using math.max to tell the highest number in my script, but i am wondering how would it be without math.max? would it be possible? just by using switch?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code only since it *may* be homework.

If it is, you should do some of the work yourself.

If it isn't you should be *able* to convert it to whatever language you want :-)

To work out the maximum and minimum of `a` and `b`:

```
def mymin(a,b):                   def mymax(a,b):
  switch (a-b):                     switch (a-b):
    case 0:                           case 0:
      return a                          return a
    default:                          default:
      switch ((a-b)/abs(a-b)):          switch ((a-b)/abs(a-b)):
        case -1:                          case -1:
          return a                          return b
        default:                          default:
          return b                          return a
```

It basically uses `(a-b)/abs(a-b)` which, assuming `a` and `b` are different will return -1 if `b > a` otherwise 1. You would get a divide-by-zero error if they were equal hence the outer switch to detect this first.

If you're looking for the minimum and maximum from a list, just set `min` and `max` initially to the first value in the list, then run through the list comparing each value with `min` and `max` and adjusting them accordingly:

```
def minAndMax(list):
    min = first element in list
    max = first element in list
    for each element e in list:
        min = mymin (min,e)
        max = mymax (max,e)
    return (min,max)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (true) {
   case a > b:
      min = b; max = a;
      break;
   case a < b:
      min = a; max = b;
      break;
   case a == b:
      // I know I could just use >= or <= 
      min = max = a;
}
```

Actually it's just uglier (or not?) form of `if - else if - else` statement.